# Как вывести изображение по нажатию кнопки с листа Item'мов GridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Подскажите пожалуйста, мне нужно чтобы по нажатию на вторую кнопку у меня на всплывающем окне выводилось изображение этого элемента GridView.  Я не могу придумать, как вывести изображение с определенного нажатого Item'а в котором находится кнопка.

```
<GridView Name="list" IsItemClickEnabled="True" Margin="0,90,0,0">
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate >
        <StackPanel Margin="10">
            <Image Width="200" Height="200" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" />
            <Grid Background="#7F9BD1D4" Height="Auto" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"  />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button Name="Car" Grid.Column="0" Content="Машина"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#7F9BD1D4"
                        Foreground="White" Click="Button_Click"/>
                <Button Name="Cat"  Grid.Column="1" Content="Кошка"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsEnabled="{Binding Act}"
                        Background="#7F9BD1D4" Foreground="White"/>
            </Grid>
            <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Title}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Выбранный элемент `GridView` хранится в свойстве `SelectedItem`. Достаете его и делаете с ним что хотите.

Comment: Мне нужно не просто отследить какой выбран элемент, мне же еще нужно к нему обратится к нему когда нажата определенная кнопка...(в этом же элементе)

Comment: Если у вас не mvvm, то обращайтесь по имени грида, то есть через list.SelectedItem

Comment: Вам же вроде как надо наоборот из кнопки к выбранному элементу обращаться, не?

Comment: Ну да, просто не представляю как это сделать) @Make Makeluv